# When using a transformer model, is numeric data also required for embedding?

Tags: pytorch, time-series, transformer-model

I am currently learning by looking at the transformer example in the link below.

[Transformer tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html)

In the example in the link, the alphabet was used as categorical data. For this reason, They used the embedding function in the model to increase the feature dimension.

But I want to apply transformer to numercial time series data. Ultimately, the goal is to predict the class of each point in time series data.
In this case, should embedding be implemented through the Linear function like the alphabet? Or can I apply the raw data directly to the model without the need for embedding?

Thanks for reading.
sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on an almost similar topic, I didn’t use embeddings in my case, first because I have a series of number not a series of vectors. If you are looking to encode a number it’s a bit tricky because by doing so you are basically setting an interval with a given precision which I don’t think it would be good if let’s say there is a progressive increasing or decreasing trend.

And since you are not encoding numbers into vectors, then injecting a wave signal into a single value would be meaningless because you would only alter the single value without any recurrence in the vector (which doesn’t exist).

Also while an encoding like one hot encoding doesn’t really give much information about the position, a value in a time series already should have a significant information about it’s position, my suggestion, is to find ways to pass the date (month, days, year) alongside the sequence.

Comment: Thank you. It was a great help in organizing my thoughts.